# SQL query remove till last occurrence and return the values

Tags: sql

Firstly, thank you for taking the time out to read this post.

I'm very much a SQL noob having trouble with a SQL SELECT query. I have a table "TableA"

TableA has 3 columns (Sequence, Height, Width) and Width has 0 at 3rd and 8th records.

My result set should consist of records from 9 onwards as we found 0  at 8th record as last occurance.

- Sequence Height  Width
- 1        20  44
- 2        21  32
- 3        30  0
- 4        1   23
- 5        4   55
- 6        6   66
- 7        33  45
- **8      6   0**
- 9        45  34
- 10       52  50
- 11       43  34
- 12       2   53
- 13       38  54

O occurs on record 3 and record 8.

My result should have records from 9 onwards.

Thank you again for your time. Please let me know if you require any more information from myself.

Comment: And where is the table and the SQL SELECT statement

Comment: This is the second time you are posting a question which is almost same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437894/sql-query-remove-till-last-occurrence-and-return-the-values)? I think you should provide more details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Sequence>(SELECT MAX(Squence) as LastOccur FROM TableA WHERE Width=0)
```

Does this fill your needs? Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I was totally new to this portal and having difficulty in indentation of the text. Now I had edited my question. Can you view it now?