# SQL query remove till last occurrence and return the values

Tags: sql

Firstly, thank you for taking the time out to read this post.

I'm very much a SQL noob having trouble with a SQL SELECT query. I have a table "TableA"

TableA has 3 columns (Height, Width) as below and Width has 0 at 3rd and 8th records.

- Height Width
- 20 44
- 21 32
- **30 0**
- 1 23
- 4 55
- 6 66
- 33 45
- **6 0**
- 45 34
- 52 50
- 43 34
- 2 53
- 38 54

0 occurs in Width column (3rd column) on record 3 and record 8.

My result set should consist of records from 9 onwards as we found 0 at 8th record as last occurance.

Thank you again for your time. Please let me know if you require any more information from myself.

Comment: What is the third column in the table?  SQL tables represent sets, so there is no inherent ordering in them.  You need a column to specify the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first column is an auto-incremented `id` of some sort, you can do this as:

```
select a.*
from tableA a
where id > (select max(id) from tableA where width = 0);
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.